# Is it possible to give runtime input to an rc file using shell module in Ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

I'm currently using the following code in ansible:

```
- shell: /file.rc
```

File.rc requires user to provide an input(1 or 2) during runtime.

If it's command line argument I can run it like below

```
- shell: /file.rc 1
```

But how to provide runtime inputs using shell module in Ansible.

Comment: A command-line argument *is* a kind of runtime input. Do you mean it's reading from stdin? Ideally, scripts that unconditionally read from stdin should be fixed to *not do that* -- to take data from the command line or argument list instead.

Comment: However, if it *is* stdin that you mean, you might want `- shell: echo 1 | /file.rc`

Comment: Yes, I want to give input using standard input. - shell: echo 1| /file.rc this works like command line arguments.

Comment: No, it does not. `echo 1 | /file.rc` feeds content on stdin, not the command line. Only with `xargs` does stdin get transformed into a command-line argument.